# pass std::istringstream as a parameter doesn't work

Tags: c++

I've just started to learn C++ 11 and I have this header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

class Parser
{
public:
    Parser();
    ~Parser();

    void Parse(const std::string& path);

private:

    std::ifstream inFile;

    void LoadFile(const std::string& path);

    void Process(const std::istringstream& in);
};
```

And this code:

```
void Parser::LoadFile(const std::string& path)
{
    if (!Exists(path))
        throw std::exception("File not found.");
    else
    {
        inFile.open(path);

        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(inFile, line))
        {
            // Input stream.
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            Process(&iss);
        }
    }
}

void Parser::Process(const std::istringstream& in)
{
}
```

But I get the following error at line `Process(&iss);`:

> there is no proper constructor to convert from "std::istringstream *"
> to "std::basic_istringstream <char, std::char_traits ,
> std::allocator >"

How do I have to declare `Process` method?

Comment: When passing by reference, you need the `&` in the function declaration/definition but ***not*** in the call. Just remove that `&` from your `Process(&iss);` call. The compiler will make the reference, for you.

Comment: When used in an expression (and not in a declaration) the `&` operator is the *pointer to* operator. It creates a pointer. For `&iss` the type will be `std::istringstream*`.

Comment: OK. I have removed the `&` in the call and now it compiles. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Reading a stream mutates it, logically at the very least, if not always bitwise. A const reference is a non-starter.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Good point! I added a note to my answer ... hope you don't mind.

Comment: @AdrianMole - I was hoping to spare future readers the next headache that comes after the immediate fix. So glad to see it incorporated.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica What does "A const reference is a non-starter" mean? I don' understand the "is a non-starter". What is "a non-starter"? Thanks

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/non-starter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` character has a variety of (sometimes very confusing) uses in C++. It can be used as the bitwise AND operator, the address-of operator and, in function declarations/definitions, to declare that a given parameter should be passed *by reference*.

In your case, the declaration, `void Process(const std::istringstream& in);`, is the third case – and is fine (other than, perhaps, using the `const` modifier<sup>1</sup>). However, in the call, `Process(&iss);`, the `&` is an address-of operator, and you are attempting to pass a *pointer* to your `iss` variable (which would be fine if the declaration were `void Process(const std::istringstream* in);`).

When a function is declared as taking an argument *by reference* (as your `Process` is), then you need only supply an *actual* variable/object as the corresponding argument in any calls to that function – the compiler will make the reference for you.

---

<sup>1</sup> As mentioned in the comments, reading an `istringstream` object (potentially) modifies it, so the `const` qualifier will likely break the code, at some point when you least expect it. (For example, just adding some dummy code to the body of `Process`, like: `int i; in >> i;` will generate a compiler error; removing the `const` qualifier will remedy that.)

Comment: I think the `const` is because I'm newbie and I put it without think about what I am doing. Maybe I have to remove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
Process(&iss);
```

`iss` is a `std::istringstream`. When used in an ***expression***, `&` is the address-of operator.

The result of the `&iss` expression is a pointer to a `std::istringstream`, or `std::istringstream *`.

```
void Process(const std::istringstream& in);
```

This declares this function as taking a *reference* to a `const std::istringstream &` as a parameter, and not a pointer.

In the context of a ***declaration***, `&` indicates a *reference type*.

`&` means different things when used in an expression or a declaration. In fact, `&` can mean something else entirely, in an expression, depending on where it appears.